# How to call a `fun func()` without calling a `fun <T> T.func()` with the same name?

Tags: kotlin

I am given a package that has two Kotlin functions named **func**: a regular `fun func()` and a generic extension `fun <T> T.func()`. They have **different** behaviour, and I'm trying to call `fun func()`. The problem is, the given scope in which I need to call `fun func()` has a receiver defined, so `fun <T> T.func()` is called instead. How do I omit the receiver parameter and avoid calling the extension function?

Kotlin Playground example: https://pl.kotl.in/rSieZpVuq

```kotlin
fun func() {
    // I need this executed
    println("Huge success!")
}
        
fun <T> T.func() {
    // I don't need this executed
    println("Complete failure!")
}

object GivenScope

fun main() {
    GivenScope.run { // this: GivenScope
        // I need it here
        func()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make it explicit: `GivenLibrary.func()`

Comment: @Jorn Sorry for the confusion, my example was not very accurate at first. func is actually a top level function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it with an explicit receiver. In your case, the method is defined on a companion object, so that's your receiver.

```
GivenScope.run { // this: GivenScope
    GivenLibrary.func()
}
```

If the function is a top-level function, you can call it with the package name as the receiver. There's no package in your example code, but if the function is in, for instance, `com.example.library`, you could write

```
com.example.library.func()
```

Comment: Oh, you're right. My example is not very accurate then, I have to clarify it. In the real given library, func is actually a top level function. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs You can call package-level functions with an explicit package name as the receiver. See the latest edit to my answer.

Comment: Oh god, of course! Works exactly as expected, thank you!

Comment: And if there was no package name, then it could be called like `FilenameKt.func()`, wouldn't it?